# Java cannot find the class file, while javap can

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javap

I have compiled a class (called Test.class) using the [Java ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/). I decided to try and ensure that I had properly compiled the class by attempting to run it using the "java" command.

However, when I did this, I got the "Could not find or load main class Test" messsage. I thought this was strange, since the class is inside the current working directory (I had also tried passing "." as the classpath, but to no avail). I then tried dissassemblng it with "javap", which worked perfectly, this is strange since if **javap** can find the class file, then surely **java** should also be able to?

Here is my command line input and output:

> $ javap -c Test

```
Compiled from "Test.ash" 
public class Test
{   
  public Test();
    Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #9 // Method "java.lang.Object"."<init>":()V
     4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
     0: return
}
```

> $ java Test
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class Test
>
> $ java Test.class
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class Test
>
> $ java -cp . Test
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class Test
>
> $ java -cp . Test.class
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class Test

What could be going wrong? I could be compiling the class incorrectly, but then surely **javap** would complain as well as **java** and the **javap** output looks correct.

Comment: Most likely it can find it but it can't load it. What's in Test.ash? It looks like you're invoking the object constructor wrong.

Comment: @DiegoBasch That's a good point actually, I should be loading the instance before calling the constructor, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @DiegoBasch I added the **aload_0** opcode but it still doesn't load. I also used **javap** on a class generated by **javac**, but the classes look the same. I have some code in my own language inside "Test.ash" which I am compiling to bytecode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, I wasn't replacing the dots in class' super-class qualified name with slashes.

So the class had the superclass of "java.lang.Object", rather than "java/lang/Object", which is required.

Comment: Are you making a custom JVM-based programming language?

Comment: @Clashsoft I am indeed :) It's called Ash. I saw yours on Github! It looks pretty cool, especially the header files.

Comment: Did you also see the 'Contributors' page? Because trust me, a lot of work awaits you :P